# calling c++ function from c# with a reference type as parameter

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke

```
 int Set(CANMsg &CANObj)
```

I have to call the method above, from c#. Untill now i have defined a wrapper :

```
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int SetWrapper(CANMsg CANObj);
```

CANMsg CANObj --- is this parameter ok or should i use CANMsg *CANObj ?

and here i implement the wrapper:

```
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int SetWrapper(CANMsg CANObj)
 { 
      return Set(CANObj);
 }
```

I am creating this wrapper because this is an overloaded version of the function and i had to make a difference somehow.

Here is the CANMsg class:

```
 class CANMsg
 {
 public:
 CANMsg();
 ~CANMsg();

 void AddRef() const;
 void Release() const;
 unsigned int MsgId;
 unsigned int DLC;
 unsigned int Handle;
 unsigned int Interval;
 unsigned int TimeStamp;
 unsigned char Data0;
 unsigned char Data1;
 unsigned char Data2;
 unsigned char Data3;
 unsigned char Data4;
 unsigned char Data5;
 unsigned char Data6;
 unsigned char Data7;

  protected:

mutable int refCount;  

};
```

Now, in C# i have the following :

```
      [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
      public class CANmsg
   {
      public  int MsgId;
      public int DLC;
      public int Handle;
      public int Interval;
      public int TimeStamp;
      public char Data0;
      public char Data1;
      public char Data2;
      public char Data3;
      public char Data4;
      public char Data5;
      public char Data6;
      public char Data7;
   }
```

and the import is like this :

```
     [DllImport("engine.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
  public static extern int SetWrapper(IntPtr canMSGObject);
```

I am a bit confused about that CANMsg object, am I declaring it ok as an IntPtr, is the marshal ok, or the types ? If i let it like so, with the IntPtr, what kind of instantiation should i perform there? If i send a CANMsg object, i get an error regarding some invalid arguments.

Let me know if you need some more details about this.

Comment: p/invoke cannot work with C++ classes. Either wrap it with a C style interface, or use C++/CLI

Comment: as David said,for your purpose the best thing to do is to create  a C++/CLI project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I see your C++ class definition, I ask myself "what happens in the constructor and the destructor?" and "what do `AddRef()` and `Release()` do?"  These are important questions because you can't simply project data from a C# object onto that IntPtr and hope for the best.  Instead, you should think about making a helper dll that does this work for you.  You might need methods something like this:

```
public ref class MyLibraryHelper {

public:
    IntPtr MakeCANMsg() { return gcnew IntPtr(new CANMsg()); }
    void DestroyCANMsg(IntPtr msgPtr) {
       CANMsg *msg = reinterpret_cast<CANMsg *>(msgPtr.ToPointer());
       if (msg) delete msg;
    }
    void ProjectTo(CSharpCANMsg ^csh, IntPtr msgPtr)
    {
       CANMsg *msg = reinterpret_cast<CANMsg *>(msgPtr.ToPointer());
       if (!msg) return;
       msg->MsgId = csh->get_MsgId();
       // etc
    }
    void ProjectFrom(IntPtr msgPtr, CSharpCANMsg ^csh)
    {
       CANMsg *msg = reinterpret_cast<CANMsg *>(msgPtr.ToPointer());
       if (!msg) return;
       csh->set_MsgId(msg->MsgId);
       // etc
    }
}
```

My C++/CLI is rusty, so expect some issues.  If this looks like hand-marshalling, well, it is because given the class that you've exposed, it seems like you need it.

Now honestly, you probably don't want this.  Really, you want a C++/CLI class that constructs a CANMsg and keeps it as a private member and then maps .NET properties onto the lower level object.  This type of class will have to be disposable and the `!ClassName()` destructor will be responsible for deleting the underlying object.

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass a C# object to native C++ like this. Marshal.StructureToPtr is what you need, the details and examples are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zhzfk83%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)